# identify link id's clicked and pass it to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

my js file has

```
$('#opt_no').click(function() {
      $('#sample6').append('<br>Employee Number:').append($("#dynamic").val());
    });

$('# opt_yes').click(function() {
      $('#sample7').append('<br>Employee Number:' ).append($("#dynamic").val());
    });
```

`opt_no` and `opt_yes` are links on my html page.
when user click on submit button, i want to identify on which link he has clicked and  pass this link id to onClick function of submit button

Comment: you need to share the relevant html

Comment: @musefan I think I misread ` i want to identify on which link he has clicked and pass this link id to onClick function of submit button`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the rest of the code. Do you want something like this?

```
$('#opt_no').click(function() {
      $('#sample6').append('<br>Employee Number:').append($("#dynamic").val());
      $("#submitlink").attr("href", $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one link can be clicked, or that the most recent clicked link is the only one you care about, then you can store the id values in a global variable. This can then be accessed from within any other function, such as your submit click event.

```
var linkId;

$('#opt_no').click(function() {
    linkId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#sample6').append('<br>Employee Number:').append($("#dynamic").val());
});

$('# opt_yes').click(function() {
    linkId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#sample7').append('<br>Employee Number:' ).append($("#dynamic").val());
});

$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    //do something with linkId
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you ca n get id using this code

```
$(this).attr('id');
```